# How to Remove Duplicate Values from Array that is added into Dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, dictionary, user-input

I have a userinput:

```
public double[] ArrayOfDoublePrecisionFloatingPointValues()
    {

        Console.Write("Enter how many values (double in C#) you want to enter in the Array of Doubles: ");
        int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());  //Convert userinput to integer
        double[] userInput = new double[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Type Double Value {0}: ", i + 1);
            userInput[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        return userInput;
    }
```

When I enter these values it creates duplicates I believe based upon how many times the for loop repeats to enter the array values based on the size established by the user.  Right now I can't see another way to get userinput to create an array.  So when I go to put the array into a Dictionary I have the same values repeated.  I don't want the array repeated.  I just want the original array the user entered.  Here is the code for the Dictionary:

```
 UserInput u = new UserInput();
       double[] userInputArray = u.ArrayOfDoublePrecisionFloatingPointValues();

        for (int i = 0; i < userInputArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if(userInputArray == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered no values!  Add values");
            }
            else if(userInputArray != null)
            {
                Dictionary<int, double> indexAndIndexValue = new Dictionary<int, double>();
                foreach (var (j, t)  in userInputArray.Enumerate())
                {
                    indexAndIndexValue.Add(j, t);
                    
                }
                foreach (var (key, value) in indexAndIndexValue)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(key + ":" + value);
                    Console.Write("------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + indexAndIndexValue.Count);
                }
```

Note that I have tried the Distinct().ToArray() to no avail.  Assistance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. `ArrayOfDoublePrecisionFloatingPointValues()` always `return`s an array even if the user specified a `size` of `0`.  When you later test `userInputArray == null` to see if you user provided any input, that test will always fail.  You either need to change `ArrayOfDoublePrecisionFloatingPointValues()` to `return null;` when `size` is `0`...

   ```cs
   public double[] ArrayOfDoublePrecisionFloatingPointValues()
   {
       Console.Write("Enter how many values (double in C#) you want to enter in the Array of Doubles: ");
       int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());  //Convert userinput to integer

       //TODO: Warn the user about negative input
       if (size < 1)
       {
           return null;
       }

       double[] userInput = new double[size];
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       {
           Console.Write("Type Double Value {0}: ", i + 1);
           userInput[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
       }

       return userInput;
   }
   ```

   ...or test for `userInputArray.Length == 0`...

   ```cs
   if (userInputArray.Length == 0)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("You have entered no values!  Add values");
   }
   else
   {
       // ...
   ```

   My code will do the latter.
2. Your `Dictionary<,>` is scoped to the `for` loop, so every iteration you are creating a new, empty `Dictionary<,>`.  Create the `Dictionary<,>` *outside* the loop so you can access it after the loop.
3. You don't need to test for "user did not provide input" in the `else` branch when the `if` branch (`userInputArray != null`/`userInputArray.Length == 0`) tested (and failed) "user did provide input".
4. You don't need to check if the user provided any input on every iteration of the `for` loop; either they did or they didn't, so your `for` should be nested inside the `if...else`, not the other way around.
5. You're adding every element of `userInputArray` (`foreach (var (j, t)  in userInputArray.Enumerate())`) for *every element of `userInputArray`* (`for (int i = 0; i < userInputArray.Length; i++)`).  Instead, you should just add the *current* index and value.

After making those changes, I end up with this...

```cs
UserInput u = new UserInput();
double[] userInputArray = u.ArrayOfDoublePrecisionFloatingPointValues();
Dictionary<int, double> indexAndIndexValue = new Dictionary<int, double>();

if (userInputArray.Length == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have entered no values!  Add values");
}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < userInputArray.Length; i++)
    {
        indexAndIndexValue.Add(i, userInputArray[i]);
    }

    foreach (var (key, value) in indexAndIndexValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(key + ":" + value);
        Console.Write("------");
        Console.WriteLine("Count: " + indexAndIndexValue.Count);
    }
}

//TODO: Use indexAndIndexValue, which may be empty
```

I moved the code that displays the contents of `indexAndIndexValue` to after the `for` loop so you can see the final contents, however, you could leave it where it was inside the `for` loop if you want to see how it changes with each iteration.

If you want to ensure that `ArrayOfDoublePrecisionFloatingPointValues()` will only `return` a `double[]` with at least one element, you might write it like this...

```cs
public double[] ArrayOfDoublePrecisionFloatingPointValues()
{
    int size;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a positive number of values (double in C#) you want to enter in the Array of Doubles: ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        
        if (!int.TryParse(input, out size) || size < 1) //Convert userinput to integer
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: \"{input}\" is not a positive integer.");
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    double[] userInput = new double[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Type Double Value {0}: ", i + 1);
        //TODO: Use double.TryParse() to reject non-Double input
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse
        userInput[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    return userInput;
}
```

[`int.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) will `return` `false` when passed non-integer input (e.g. `""`, `"ABC"`, `"123.456"`) and, if it `return`s `true`, we then test to make sure it's a positive `int`, too.

Comment: I am going to check it.  I may have found another solution without using the Dictionary through .NET, but this is another solution too.  Thank you for answering!!!

Comment: I see.  If the `Dictionary<,>` isn't required then a `double[]` or `List<double>` would work just as well to "map" an index to a value.  Also, I have updated my answer with an alternative implementation of `ArrayOfDoublePrecisionFloatingPointValues()` that always `return`s _some_ user-provided values.